# Exception during xgboost prediction: can not initialize DMatrix from DMatrix

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, google-cloud-ml

I trained a xgboost model in Python using the Scikit-Learn Python API, and serialized it using `pickle` library. I uploaded the model to ML Engine, but when I try to do online predictions, i get the following exception:

```
Prediction failed: Exception during xgboost prediction: can not initialize DMatrix from DMatrix
```

An example of the json I'm using for prediction is the following:

```
{  
   "instances":[  
      [  
         24.90625,
         21.6435643564356,
         20.3762376237624,
         24.3679245283019,
         30.2075471698113,
         28.0947368421053,
         16.7797359774725,
         14.9262079299572,
         17.9888028979966,
         15.3333284503293,
         19.6535308744024,
         17.1501961307627,
         0.0,
         0.0,
         0.0,
         0.0,
         0.0,
         509.0,
         497.0,
         439.0,
         427.0,
         407.0,
         1.0,
         1.0,
         1.0,
         1.0,
         1.0,
         2.0,
         23.0,
         10.0,
         58.0,
         11.0,
         20.0,
         23.3617021276596,
         23.3617021276596,
         23.3617021276596,
         23.3617021276596,
         23.3617021276596,
         23.9423076923077,
         26.3082269243683,
         23.6212606363851,
         22.6752334301282,
         27.4343583104833,
         34.0090408101173,
         11.1991944104063,
         7.33420726455092,
         8.15160392948917,
         11.4119236389594,
         17.9429092915607,
         18.0573102225845,
         32.8902876598084,
         -0.00286123032904149,
         -0.00286123032904149,
         -0.00286123032904149,
         -0.00286123032904149,
         -0.00286123032904149,
         -0.0028328611898017,
         0.0534138904223018,
         0.0534138904223018,
         0.0534138904223018,
         0.0534138904223018,
         0.0534138904223018,
         0.0531491870801522
      ]
   ]
}
```

I use the following code to train my model:

```
def _train_model(X, y):
    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=6,
                            learning_rate=0.01,
                            n_estimators=100,
                            n_jobs=-1)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf
```

Where `X` and `y` are both `numpy.ndarray`:

```
Type of X: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> Type of y: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Also I'm using `xgboost 0.72.1`, `Python 3.5` and ML runtime `1.9`.

Any one knows what can be the source of the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `print(type(X))`

Comment: @EranMoshe `X` and `y` are both `numpy.ndarray` (I added this to the question)

Comment: Not in the training. When predicting.

Comment: For prediction I use ML Engine and send the json using the REST API with the key "instances" and the value a list of list. The example json is in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like the issue is due to the pickling. I was able to reproduce it and working on a fix, but meanwhile could you try exporting your classifier like below instead?

```
clf._Booster.save_model('./model.bst')
```

That should unblock you for now. If it didn't, feel free to reach out to `cloudml-feedback@google.com`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how you should load back such a model, @N3da?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem or feature mismatch when I tried score the test data using the the trained XGBoost model that was dumped in .pkl format. 
However after saving the model in .bst format, I was able to score the same training data without any issues. Looks like there is a difference in the two implementations of .pkl and .bst format when it comes to XGBoost.

Answer (score 0):

Going a little further, and answering kuza's question above on loading the saved model:

save model:

```
clf._Booster.save_model('./model.bst')
```

loading the saved model:

```
model = xgboost.Booster({'nthread': 4})  # initialize before loading model
model.load_model('./model.bst')  # load model
```

This cleared up 2 issues that I had with using pickle on the model. Issue 1 was a weird exeption: ValueError: feature_names mismatch:

Also check if you are using predict_proba on the loaded model, and getting a weird exception. The fix for that was just to use the straight predict function vice predict_proba.